# Remove Span tag with text from String

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a string as follows:

```
<span class="exam-dates-title">Exam</span>Welcome
```

How to completely remove `<div>` start and `</div>` end tag from the above string in Android?

> I need to display **Welcome** only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you:

```
String yourString = "<span class=\"exam-dates-title\">Exam</span>Welcome";
int index = yourString.lastIndexOf(">");

String result = yourString.substring(index + 1, yourString.length());
```

Comment: Thank you sir.this is more helpful .But i got more number of span how to separate particular string to display Welcome Like this **<div>
 <span class="tooltip" ng-if="ShowExamDate"><span class="tooltip">
 <span class="exam-dates-title">Exam</span><span class="exam-dates-container"><span class="exam-date">FSM</span></span></span></span><span class="img-link"><strong type="bold">Monster</strong> = Welcome to monster world.</span></div>**

Comment: @Alish This case try to play around: CharSequence result = Html.fromHtml(yourString);

Comment: Thank you sir. This CharSequence result = Html.fromHtml(yourString); same as like a String text= text.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""); all tags removed. But did't removed text inside tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the text between `<div>` and `</div>`, replace all `<[\w\s\d\\=\-"]+>`  for leading tag, and `</[\w\s\d\\=\-"]+>` for ending tag.

It will replace zero or more `\w` words, `\s` spaces, `\d` digits inside the tag. Add any other symbol inside `[ ]` if needed.

If you want remove the tag `<div>` `</div>` and the text inside, use [Pattern and Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), find the index of `<div>` and `</div>` and replace it. I think this is a safer method to do this. Use `indexOf(">")` or `indexOf("<")` might be wrong if there are < or > in your string but it is not a tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex will match a span tag, including its attributes, contents and end tag.

```
<span.*>.*</span>
```

Do a find/replace on your string (see the following https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary) and replace the matches with "".

You might want to look into the "non-greedy" option.

Comment: Thank you sir. But i need total span removed like this String getNew1 = getNew.replaceAll("[<](/)?span[^>]*[>]", ""); this line only removed span tag not text.

Comment: Try .replaceAll("<span.*>.*</span>", ""), alternatively for lazy capturing, .replaceAll("<span.*?>.*?</span>", "")